# Trying to verify persistence on data of os x application

Tags: xcode, core-data, persistence

I have created an Xcode 11 OS X targeted program to persist with CoreData.  I want to verify the contents of  written records on the disk.  I have read that persistence is implemented by Xcode using SQLite. I have so far been unable to find such a file.

I apologize in advance for not knowing how to use code fences.  I've included a line in the code which I had hoped would provide the  path to any saved files but after searching the folder I find no ".db" files

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName:   "Plants", in: context)
        let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        print(paths[0])
        newUser.setValue("James B", forKey: "name")
        newUser.setValue("Spring", forKey: "fertilizeSeason")
        do {
           try context.save()
          } catch {
           print("Failed saving")
        }
    }
```

Hoped to find .db file at the returned path.

Comment: Any pointers to learning about code fences are welcome

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: When you have additional information to add to your question, it is good practice to edit your question and add that information. So in the future, when others visit your post, all the information will be in one place, so it is easier to read and respond to your problem. Leave the comments just for comments.

Comment: Are you aware of the Terminal app in macOS? Using Terminal, you can access the directory in which your database file resides and use commands to open the file and interrogate the persisted data. It’s a useful skill to have.

Comment: The files are .sqlite not .db and probably in `~/Library/Application Support`.

Comment: Thanks to all for the contributions toward solving my question. Still haven't found the file yet, but now I know what to look for.  The terminal app suggestion is a good one.   I was mostly a Windows guy back in the day.  But I've come over to the good side of the force now.  I'll do some homework on that.  The good news is that I have been able to successfully fetch the persistent data from my program.  But I still want to find that pesky Sqlite file.